# Clients continue to reload after restarting rocket server

Tags: rocket.chat

I am running 0.37.1 docker images with an nginx proxy in the front. Running on RH7 instance.

Whenever I restart the Rocket chat server the clients on my mac and Android phone both have issues.

The mac client will continually refresh. I have to remove the server and add it again to stop the refresh.

For the android client I get the notification of the new version and select to update but then it does not download the changed files and is stuck on the downloading files screen.

Has anyone see these issues before?

Comment: Does this still happen?  By continually refresh do you mean that it literally is refreshing the whole page?  Or that it shows a banner across the top with a connection retry with a backoff on the retries?

Comment: What you see is the page refreshing in the client and if you are watching the user screen you see them come online and go offline regularly. You can't use the interface .

Comment: This should definitely be resolved in newer versions of Rocket.Chat and the clients

Comment: This is still and issue as I have recently completed an upgrade and this still happens

Comment: I have a feeling this may have something to do with the DDP address.  What environment variables do you have set?

Comment: We are decommissioning the server now and the company is going with Hipchat so my time is running out on Rocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are decommissioning the Rocket server so we will not be using it much longer so I don't anticipate updating it again. 
Thanks for all the answers and suggestions